# TextMate question: how to move caret to next/previous blank line

Tags: textmate

See title. Is there already a simple key combination that does this that I can't find in the manual? Is there a command I can put in KeyBindings.dict to do this?

I was hoping `moveToBeginningOfParagraph:` would do it but that appears to just go to the beginning of the current line.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if it's built in, or if you can do it via an Emacs shortcut, but you can do it.

Record the following:

Open the Find dialog box. Click Regular expression, and find the following:

```
^$
```

Save this macro.

Comment: more or less, yeah. I wanted to use it to simulate emacs `M-{` and `M-}` so for my purposes I used `^\s*$`. But thanks for the tip...textmate macros are sweet.